# Terminal Command to install apps on ubuntu-touch?

Tags: software-installation, ubuntu-touch

I have to reset my Ubuntu Phone but I want to automatically reinstall the apps that I have. With `click list` I can get the installed apps, but how can I reinstall them on the terminal?

apt-get leads to an error.

Answer (score 2):

There is currently no command line tool to install applications from the store, and currently no way to automatically re-install previously installed applications.